# Multiple orderby values in WP_Query

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, wp-query

I'm trying to come up with a query to sort by multiple orderby values. Here's what I have so far:

```
    $dept_id=2;
    $query=new WP_Query(array(
            'post_type'=>'wpcontactus',
            'nopaging'=>true,
            'post_status'=>array('publish', 'pending', 'future'),
            'meta_key'=>'wcu_dept',
            'meta_value'=>$dept_id,
            'orderby'=>'title',
            'order'=>'ASC'
    ));
```

I'm trying to query a custom post type, and within that post type, query a meta value.

Then, I'd like to first sort by `menu_order` ascending, then by a custom meta value `wcu_lastname` ascending. However, the orderby value didn't seem to be able to take an array.

How can I order the query using multiple orderby values?

Comment: If I'm not wrong, simply add them space separated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$query=new WP_Query(array(
                'post_type'=>'wpcontactus',
                'nopaging'=>true,
                'post_status'=>array('publish', 'pending', 'future'),
                'meta_query'=>array(
                                array('key'=>'wcu_dept','value'=>$dept_id, 'compare'=>'='),
                            ),
                'meta_key'=>'wcu_firstname',
                'orderby'=>'menu_order wcu_firstname',
                'order'=>'ASC'
        ));
```

By using what @kaiser suggested and the `meta_query` option, I was able to get the query I was looking for.

Comment: how can we put multiple order value for the fields? For ex: ASC for menu_order, DESC for date

Answer (score 35):

@Musa 
how can we put multiple order value for the fields?
I was wondering the same question and I found this :

> In 4.0, you can now pass an array to WP_Query as the value for
>   orderby.

The syntax looks like:

```
$q = new WP_Query( array( 
    'orderby' => array( 
       'title'      => 'DESC', 
       'menu_order' => 'ASC' 
    ) 
));
```

Have a look here for more details : 
https://make.wordpress.org/core/2014/08/29/a-more-powerful-order-by-in-wordpress-4-0/

Answer (score 0):

```
    $args = [
        's'              => $keyword,
        'post_type'      => ['page'],
        'paged'          => $paged,
        'posts_per_page' => PAGE_LIMIT,
        'tax_query' => [
             [
                  'taxonomy'         => TAX_RESOURCE_PAGE,
                  'field'            => 'slug',
                  'terms'            => $c_term_slug
             ],
        ],
        'post_status'    => 'publish',
        'meta_key'       => 'order',
        'meta_type'      => 'NUMERIC',
        'orderby'        => [
             'meta_value_num' => 'ASC',
             'ID' => 'DESC',
        ],
    ];
    $wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

my code is a example.