# Setting multiple values to as sort_column

Tags: wp-list-pages

If I want to sort on 1) menu_order and if the pages weight the same I want to 2) sort them alphabetically, how? Is this the default behavior if you set menu_order?

Is it?:

```
$args = array(
    'sort_order' => 'ASC',
    'sort_column' => 'menu_order, post_title'
);
$children = get_pages($args);
```

Or?:

```
$args = array(
    'sort_order' => 'ASC',
    'sort_column' => 'menu_order post_title'
);
```

Or?:

```
$args = array(
    'sort_order' => 'ASC',
    'sort_column' => 'menu_order | post_title'
);
```

Or?:

```
$args = array(
    'sort_order' => 'ASC',
    'sort_column' => array('menu_order', 'post_title')
);
```

etc...

From wp_query it seems like it would be a simple space? [Multiple orderby values in WP_Query](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/65769/multiple-orderby-values-in-wp-query)

Should really be in the spec.!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`get_pages` explodes `sort_column` on the comma (`,`) character. [Just check the source:](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.6.1/wp-includes/post.php#L3722)

```
foreach ( explode( ',', $sort_column ) as $orderby ) {
```

So the correct format should be the first one you posted:

```
$args = array(
    'sort_order' => 'ASC',
    'sort_column' => 'menu_order, post_title'
);
$children = get_pages($args);
```

If you are not seeing the ordering you expect it is probably because of how the `ASC` is applied. [The `ASC` sort order is going to be applied to the last item in the list, not to all of them](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.6.1/wp-includes/post.php#L3755).

```
3755            $query = "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts $join WHERE ($where_post_type) $where ";
3756            $query .= $author_query;
3757            $query .= " ORDER BY " . $sort_column . " " . $sort_order ;
```

That  `ASC` is tacked onto the SQL after the complete `ORDER BY` statement resulting in something like this: `ORDER BY menu_order, post_title ASC`. I suspect that you want `ORDER BY menu_order ASC, post_title` or `ORDER BY menu_order ASC, post_title ASC` instead.

To get either of those results, you will need to use `WP_Query` because the SQL used by `get_pages` is pretty rigid and not easily filtered [as it uses `$wpdb->get_results` directly](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.6.1/wp-includes/post.php#L3762).

You will still need a filter, though, as `WP_Query` handles `order` the same way that `get_pages` does.

```
function alter_order_wpse_115183($orderby) {
  remove_action('posts_orderby','alter_order_wpse_115183');
  $pattern = '([^ ]+) (ASC|DESC)$';
  preg_match('/'.$pattern.'/',$orderby,$matches);
  if (empty($matches[2])) {
    return $orderby;
  }
  if (!empty($matches[1])) {
    $order = str_replace(',',' '.$matches[2].',',$matches[1]).' '.$matches[2];
    // or
    // $order = str_replace(',',' '.$matches[2].',',$matches[1]);
  }
  return $order;
}
add_action(
  'posts_orderby',
  'alter_order_wpse_115183'
);
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'page',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'orderby' => 'menu_order title'
);
$children = new WP_Query($args);
var_dump($children->request);

$children = new WP_Query($args);
var_dump($children->request); die;
```

Comment: Thanks for the correct answer! I just wanted to point out that MySQL Default sort order, when using ORDER BY, is ascending and that's what I wanted anyway but it's good to know how it works and how you would solve it otherwise also. Thanks! http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sorting-rows.html

Answer (score 0):

This also works perfectly in wp_list_pages:

```
<?php wp_list_pages('title_li=&sort_column=menu_order,post_title'); ?>
```